# Enabling gZip Compression using tomcat-maven plugin

Tags: tomcat, plugins, maven

In our spring application, we want to compress the response using gzip compression, from the documentation i found out that we can configure it by modifying /conf/server.xml file in tomcat (http://www.servletworld.com/tomcat/enable-tomcat-gzip-compression.html).

But in our app, we are using embedded tomcat from org.codehaus.mojo plugin, 
From some research, i can see that we can do such server configurations in pom.xml as below :

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <port>${tomcat.port}</port>
            <url>${tomcat.manager}</url>
            <username>${tomcat.manager.username}</username>
            <password>${tomcat.manager.password}</password>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Similarly i wanted to configure the connector attributes for enabling compression, tried out different ways but with no success.

Can someone please help me out.

Thanks

Shri

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like maven tomcat plugin allows you to do this, but [tomcat:run](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) goal seems to provide a `serverXml` parameter, using which you can specify your own `server.xml` with compression attributes enabled.